Cross-reference expl3 integers with cleveref
Suppose I implement numbered document elements using expl3 integers. Suppose further that I would like to cross-reference these elements using cleveref. What is the best way to do this?
I came up with the following, which seems to work in somewhat minimal testing, but doesn't seem especially safe.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\g_my_counter_int
\keys_define:nn { my / topic thing }
{%
  label .tl_set:N = \l_my_label_tl,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \topicthing  { O{} m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { my / topic thing } { #1 }
  \phantomsection
  \int_gincr:N \g_my_counter_int
  #2
  \my_label_set:Nn \g_my_counter_int { topic }
  \label {topic:\l_my_label_tl}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_label_set:Nn
{
  \edef\@currentlabel{\int_use:N #1}
  \cref@constructprefix {#2} {\cref@result}
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{
    [#2] [\int_use:N #1] [\cref@result]
    \int_to_arabic:n { #1 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\crefname{topic}{topic}{topics}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\topicthing[label=first]{First Topic}

\topicthing[label=second]{Second Topic}

\ref{topic:first}

\ref{topic:second}

\Cref{topic:first}

\Cref{topic:second}
\end{document}

As far as I can tell, this gives the target output in terms of numbering, linking etc. The .aux file also looks reasonable, although I'm not sure what every part of the information cleveref writes is supposed to be for:
\relax
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\providecommand\BKM@entry[2]{}
\newlabel{topic:first}{{1}{1}{}{section*.1}{}}
\newlabel{topic:first@cref}{{[topic][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{topic:second}{{2}{1}{}{section*.2}{}}
\newlabel{topic:second@cref}{{[topic][2][]2}{[1][1][]1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}

Certainly it is recording the type of the cross-reference correctly, though I don't know if the blanks should be filled. But standard cases also feature blanks in some cases ....
However, while isn't quite as much fun as getting \cref to work with a \label in a tcolorbox, it's still not pretty at all.
Is there a better way to do this?

Update
Thanks to Ulrike's comment, I now have
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\g_my_counter_int
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_creu_targed:n
{
  \MakeLinkTarget* {#1}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_creu_targed_from_int:nN
{
  \my_creu_targed:n {#1.\int_use:N #2}
}
\keys_define:nn { my / topic thing }
{%
  label .tl_set:N = \l_my_label_tl,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \topicthing  { O{} m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { my / topic thing } { #1 }
  \int_gincr:N \g_my_counter_int
  \my_creu_targed_from_int:nN { topic } \g_my_counter_int
  #2
  \my_label_set:Nn \g_my_counter_int { topic }
  \label {topic:\l_my_label_tl}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_label_set:Nn
{
  \edef\@currentlabel{\int_use:N #1}
  \cref@constructprefix {#2} {\cref@result}
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{
    [#2] [\int_use:N #1] [\cref@result]
    \int_to_arabic:n { #1 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\crefname{topic}{topic}{topics}
\makeatother
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\topicthing[label=first]{First Topic}

\kant[1-3]

\topicthing[label=second]{Second Topic}

\kant[4-5]

\ref{topic:first}

\ref{topic:second}

\Cref{topic:first}

\Cref{topic:second}

\Cref{topic:first,topic:second}
\end{document}

which produces a clearer .aux:
\relax
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\providecommand\BKM@entry[2]{}
\newlabel{topic:first}{{1}{1}{}{topic.1}{}}
\newlabel{topic:first@cref}{{[topic][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{topic:second}{{2}{1}{}{topic.2}{}}
\newlabel{topic:second@cref}{{[topic][2][]2}{[1][1][]1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{2}

Although I will need to do something for cases where I'm reusing the integer rather than incrementing it. So maybe something like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\g_my_counter_int
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_creu_targed:n
{
  \MakeLinkTarget* {#1}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_creu_targed_from_int:nN
{
  \my_creu_targed:n {#1.\int_use:N #2}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_creu_targed_from_intc:nN
{
  \MakeLinkTarget [ #1.\int_use:N #2 c ] {}
}
\keys_define:nn { my / topic thing }
{%
  label .tl_set:N = \l_my_label_tl,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \topicthing  { O{} m s }
{
  \keys_set:nn { my / topic thing } { #1 }
  \IfBooleanTF { #3 }
  {
    \my_creu_targed_from_intc:nN { topic } \g_my_counter_int
    #2

    \my_label_set:Nn \g_my_counter_int { topic }
    \label {topic:\l_my_label_tl-c} 
  }{
    \int_gincr:N \g_my_counter_int
    \my_creu_targed_from_int:nN { topic } \g_my_counter_int
    #2
    \my_label_set:Nn \g_my_counter_int { topic }
    \label {topic:\l_my_label_tl} 
  }
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_label_set:Nn
{
  \edef\@currentlabel{\int_use:N #1}
  \cref@constructprefix {#2} {\cref@result}
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{
    [#2] [\int_use:N #1] [\cref@result]
    \int_to_arabic:n { #1 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\crefname{topic}{topic}{topics}
\makeatother
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\topicthing[label=first]{First Topic}

\kant[1-3]

\topicthing[label=second]{Second Topic}

\kant[4-5]

\section{Something Else}\label{sec:else}

\ref{topic:first}

\ref{topic:second}

\topicthing[label=scont]{Second Topic Cont.}

\kant[6]

\Cref{topic:first}

\Cref{topic:second}

\Cref{topic:scont}

\Cref{sec:else}

\Cref{topic:first,topic:second,topic:scont}
\end{document}

which gives
\relax
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\providecommand\BKM@entry[2]{}
\BKM@entry{id=1,dest={746F7069632E31},srcline={1083}}{5C3337365C3337375C303030465C303030695C303030725C303030735C303030745C3030305C3034305C303030545C3030306F5C303030705C303030695C30303063}
\BKM@entry{id=2,dest={746F7069632E32},srcline={1087}}{5C3337365C3337375C303030535C303030655C303030635C3030306F5C3030306E5C303030645C3030305C3034305C303030545C3030306F5C303030705C303030695C30303063}
\newlabel{topic:first}{{1}{1}{\contentsname \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }{\MakeUppercase \contentsname }}{topic.1}{}}
\newlabel{topic:first@cref}{{[topic][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{First Topic}{1}{topic.1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{topic:second}{{2}{1}{\contentsname \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \contentsname }{\MakeUppercase \contentsname }}{topic.2}{}}
\newlabel{topic:second@cref}{{[topic][2][]2}{[1][1][]1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{Second Topic}{1}{topic.2}\protected@file@percent }
\BKM@entry{id=3,dest={73656374696F6E2E31},srcline={1090}}{5C3337365C3337375C303030535C3030306F5C3030306D5C303030655C303030745C303030685C303030695C3030306E5C303030675C3030305C3034305C303030455C3030306C5C303030735C30303065}
\BKM@entry{id=4,dest={746F7069632E33},srcline={1097}}{5C3337365C3337375C303030535C303030655C303030635C3030306F5C3030306E5C303030645C3030305C3034305C303030545C3030306F5C303030705C303030695C303030635C3030305C3034305C303030435C3030306F5C3030306E5C303030745C3030302E}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Something Else}{2}{section.1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{sec:else}{{1}{2}{Something Else}{section.1}{}}
\newlabel{sec:else@cref}{{[section][1][]1}{[1][2][]2}}
\newlabel{topic:scont}{{3}{2}{Something Else}{topic.3}{}}
\newlabel{topic:scont@cref}{{[topic][3][]3}{[1][2][]2}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{Second Topic Cont.}{2}{topic.3}\protected@file@percent }
\gdef \@abspage@last{3}

In real life, the topics are created at the chapter level and may be numbered or not, but they may also be split, which is why an integer may be used without incrementing it. I didn't bother reproducing the numbers for the example.

Note that I'm aware that I could use a 2e counter and \refstepcounter!

My first impression is that a better way would be to use \refstepcounter... ;-) You know that, of course, but you didn't tell us why the need to use an expl3 int at all? (theoretical exercise?). Other than that, zref-clever would let you reference an arbitrary zref property and get access to the somewhat more flexible zref machinery, but I suppose that's not what you are looking for.

Side note: as far as I can tell, the .aux file results look reasonable. I think the empty field would be for within counters, which makes sense to be empty for an expl3 counter...

Thanks @gusbrs. That's helpful. It also tells me what should probably get written when I've got a within case. Re. why: originally, I did explain, but I deleted it as boring and hand-wavey. Basically, I will go back to fancyref if the alternative is picking out all the ints from my code. I didn't anticipate this problem when I rewrote the code in mostly-expl3. Generally, that has main extension and maintenance much easier and the code a lot clearer. But not, I admit, in this case.

@gusbrs Actually, I looked at zref-clever. A minor query was whether it supports the same sort/compression and how hard it would be to update a .cfg. But my major reason not to go that route is that I really can't afford to use a package for this particular class which might break backwards compatibility. Also, if I was going to go that route, I'd probably look at ltproperties first.

I actually don't care much in this case about automatically tracking the type. If there was a cleveref compress/sort package which worked with fancyref style config, that would be fine. (OK, the fancyref config is tediously verbose, but I'm sure I could avoid that if I wanted to. The main thing people don't like is having to manually ensure the correct prefixes. That's not really a problem most of the time.)

It seems your MWE is more simplified than your actual use case. That said, the only thing I can add is, yes, ltproperties is a good alternative and do not forget that nowadays you have the very useful label hook in the kernel, so that you can sneak your ltproperties label into the standard \label without any ugly hacks. :-) You just don't get to refer to it with the standard \ref, but it is easy enough to get what you want also.

About fancyref, I'm not sure what you are trying to get from it, but the "type" is usually the "counter" (or easily derived from it), and you have access to it with the "counter" property in either ltproperties or zref (tracking the value of \@currentcouter). zref-clever does have similar sort and compression to cleveref, it does take some work to adapt configuration, but that's usually something to be done at document level, not at the class level. So, yes, if that's the kind of thing you are doing, you likely have your hands tied.

@gusbrs the "type" is usually the "counter" (or easily derived from it), but not in fancyref. In my case, the type is only sometimes the counter. Not just in this class. Generally. Otherwise I'd switched to cleveref long ago. What I really want is a package which works exactly the way I want it to work ;). I just can't imagine why it doesn't seem to exist :(.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I would replace \phantomsection with a \MakeLinkTarget  (see hyperref-linktarget.pdf) to get a proper destination name like topic.1 instead of section*.1, this will allow to make use of autoref too.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks. I'd never heard of \MakeLinkTarget. I did consider creating link targets using hyperref's commands, but it seemed unnecessarily complicated. I might avoid autoref, though. I don't think I'm capable of dealing with two referencing packages at once, never mind three.

\autoref is not a package but a command from hyperref.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks. I shouldn't have put it like that. I just meant: it's a third approach to extending cross-referencing and I'm already having enough trouble with two. Plus my only reason to switch to cleveref is the sorting/compressing, which \autoref doesn't do, as far as I know. Have I misunderstood?

\autoref doesn't really extend cross-referencing, not in the way cleveref does, like \ref or \pageref or \nameref it makes use of what is in the standard label (the target name), and it doesn't harm to create a suitable name, just in case a user wants to use \autoref once in a while.

@UlrikeFischer Oh, I see. Yes. That makes sense now. I'm unlikely to use \autoref, I guess, and I don't think anybody else would have any use for this code. But it's better anyway to have meaningful labels in the .aux, even if they're never technically used. It does mean I need this after I've incremented the int, which changes the target position in some cases, but that's probably worth it. Whether I'm using \MakeLinkTarget correctly is another matter.
